# Not able to read uncommitted offsets after restart Listener in Spring boot

Tags: spring-kafka

I am trying to commit the offsets in Kafka on basis of certain conditions.
Here is my listener code.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "test")
public void getTopics(@RequestBody String emp,Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
    
Employee model = gson.fromJson(emp, Employee.class);
if(model.getId()%2!=0)
{
    System.out.println("Kafka event consumed is: " + emp);
    acknowledgment.acknowledge();
}

else {
    System.out.println("Model converted value: " + model); 
}
}
```

Here is my application.prop file configurations

```
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=manual-immediate
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

At first when i start the springboot app then i am passing some even employee id in topic.
Then i restart my program after making `if(model.getId()%2==0)` which is opposite condition.I am able to fetch the values which i had not commited first.

I retry the same process by adding `spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false` in application.properties.But this time consumer doesn't retry for earlier.I had thought that i should have been able to get what i was getting earlier and in first case it should not have worked as auto-commit should be false for committing.
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Individual records are not acknowledged, Kafka only maintains a committed offset for each group/topic/partition. If you have 2 records (offset 0 and 1) and you acknowledge the second one, but not the first, the committed offset is now 2; you will not get 0 again.

Comment: @GaryRussell thanks a lot for helping. It cleared my many confusions at once. I now understand why it is designed like that. If it starts picking the older ones before last committed  then there can be many unrequired historical records present  which is no use and it would have been overhead to scan it again.

Comment: @GaryRussell I am new to Kafka and Spring. I have read alot of your  answers and try to understand it what it says.I found this one quite beginner friendly and useful. https://github.com/SpringOnePlatform2016/grussell-spring-kafka.If you could  please point out some similar ones,it would be much help.Thanks a lot.

Comment: There are a few more samples here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/tree/main/samples I have answered many questions here on SO https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1240763%20%5bspring-kafka%5d Also see the [reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/).

Comment: @GaryRussell thanks so much:))